# Ruby - Search/Compare Excel workbook for specific term and append found results to csv?

Tags: ruby, excel, search, csv, comparison

Okay so I've been messing around with Ruby quite a bit but am still fairly new at it.  I am running into a problem with my current program. What I want it to do is take a CSV file which contains a list of terms, I then take the csv file and create an array of those terms.  Once I have those terms in an array I want to search an Excel workbook and find all occurances of that term...in all sheets.  If a term is found it will be appended to a csv file with the sheet name and cell location it is found at.  I think I have a fairly good start at it.

EDIT: I am no longer recieving any errors. It just simply recreates the given file.  It does not seem to be dropping into the workbook and doing the compares? Any ideas?

EDIT 2: Used print statements it is something wrong with my if strings are equals condition.

EDIT 3: I isololated the issue to my compare.  When I use the `term` variable it gets the term as `["theterm"]` and then trys to compare it to a string which will always be false...

My code is below:

```
require 'roo'

$termsarray = Array.new

puts "Please enter filepath of file of terms (C:/path/to/file.csv)"
#termspath = gets.chomp.to_s
termspath = "C:/Ruby/termslist.csv"

CSV.foreach( "#{termspath}") do |row|   
  $termsarray << row
end
puts "Added terms to array successfully"

puts "Please enter filepath of file to cross-reference (C:/path/to/file.xlsx)"
#filepath = gets.chomp.to_s
filepath = "C:/Ruby/file_to_crossreference.xlsx"
puts "Please enter filepath for output file (C:/path/to/file.csv)"
output = gets.chomp.to_s

w1 = Excelx.new ( "#{filepath}" )
CSV.open( "#{output}", "w") do |csv|   
$termsarray.each do |term|
csv << term
  w1.sheets.each do |sheet|
    w1.default_sheet = sheet
    if w1.first_row && w1.first_column
      eval(w1.to_s).each do |index, value|
        if term.to_s.chomp.eql? value.to_s.chomp
          csv << [sheet, convert_index(index.to_s), value]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
print "File Indexed Successfully!"
end
```

Comment: Try to isolate the code that is causing the error and post just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed and found my problem.  When creating the list of terms I was accidently creating an array of arrays.  The code is below however it may not be the best, especially if the data is in multiple columns and such.

```
CSV.foreach( "#{termspath}") do |row|  
  #Will only take first item in first column of each row
  string = row[0.to_i].to_s
  $termsarray << string
end
```